# Error loading ads: Unable to request ads from server due to network error

Tags: ios, google-dfp

While executing a basic sample (https://github.com/googleads/googleads-ima-ios/releases), I am getting above error.

[image: Xcode Screen]

The ad tag that i am using is: https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=640x480&iu=/124319096/external/single_ad_samples&ciu_szs=300x250&impl=s&gdfp_req=1&env=vp&output=vast&unviewed_position_start=1&cust_params=deployment%3Ddevsite%26sample_ct%3Dlinear&correlator=

I am using SDK for iOS : 3.3.1

If I execute the same tag on "https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/flash/vastinspector" 
it works fine.

And lastly, I am running it on Simulator for iPad Air.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it was an issue with Firewall. 
Removing my machine from firewall protection.
Fixed my issue.